# CSS: Issue with Lines Connecting Tree Nodes

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, sass

I am working on a drawing lines connecting tree nodes, I was able to it achieve more or less, but there are some dangling lines etc that I want to get rid of.

Here is the codepen implementation:-  https://codepen.io/Dinesh443/pen/wvWjJeB

I am trying to get rid of the connecting line before the root node and also the other dangling lines after the last node as highlighted below.

[image]

Although the code is written in Vue js, it's a simple recursive tree representation using 'ul' and 'li' tags. I've used the ::before, ::after. psuedo selector to achieve this.

HTML:-

```
<div class="container">
  <h4>Vue.js Expandable Tree Menu<br/><small>(Recursive Components)</small></h4>
  <div id="app">
  <tree-menu 
             :nodes="tree.nodes" 
             :depth="0"   
             :label="tree.label"
             ></tree-menu>
  </div>
</div>


<script type="text/x-template" id="tree-menu">
  <div class="tree-menu">
    <li>
    <div class="label-wrapper" @click="toggleChildren">
      <div :class="labelClasses">
        <i v-if="nodes" class="fa" :class="iconClasses"></i>
        {{ label }}
      </div>
    </div>
     <ul>
    <tree-menu 
      v-if="showChildren"
      v-for="node in nodes" 
      :nodes="node.nodes" 
      :label="node.label"
      :depth="depth + 1"   
    >
  </ul>
    </tree-menu>
  </li>
  </div>
</script>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1em;
}

.container {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.tree-menu {
  .label-wrapper {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    // border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    .has-children {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  }
}

.tree-menu li {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin:5px;
    position: relative;
}

.tree-menu li>ul::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top:-7px;
    left:-30px;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius:0 0 0 0px;
    // width:20px;
    height:100%;
}

.tree-menu li>ul::after {
    content:"";
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    top:8px;
    left:-30px;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top:1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius:0px 0 0 0;
    width:20px;
    height:100%;
}
```

JavaScript( Vue ):

```
let tree = {
  label: 'root',
  nodes: [
    {
      label: 'item1',
      nodes: [
        {
          label: 'item1.1'
        },
        {
          label: 'item1.2',
          nodes: [
            {
              label: 'item1.2.1'
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }, 
    {
      label: 'item2'  
    }
  ]
}

Vue.component('tree-menu', { 
  template: '#tree-menu',
  props: [ 'nodes', 'label', 'depth' ],
  data() {
     return {
       showChildren: false
     }
  },
  computed: {
    iconClasses() {
      return {
        'fa-plus-square-o': !this.showChildren,
        'fa-minus-square-o': this.showChildren
      }
    },
    labelClasses() {
      return { 'has-children': this.nodes }
    },
    // indent() {
    //   return { transform: `translate(${this.depth * 50}px)` }
    // }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleChildren() {
       this.showChildren = !this.showChildren;
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    tree
  }
})
```

Comment: I am still stuck at this, I was able to get rid of the line before the root node using not:first-child property, but the rest of the dangling lines are somehow still available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this the result you are looking for?

your "dangling lines" is just wrongly calculated height of :before element.

```css
.tree-menu-1st-example ul {
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.tree-menu-1st-example ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 30px;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 2em;
}

.tree-menu-1st-example ul li:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 0px;
  height: 100%;
}

.tree-menu-1st-example ul li:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em;
  left: 0px;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0px 0 0 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 100%;
}

.tree-menu-1st-example ul li:last-of-type:before {
  height: 1em;
}

/* new example: */

.tree-menu-2 ul {
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.tree-menu-2 ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 30px;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 2em;
}

.tree-menu-2 ul .tree-menu-2{
  position:relative;
}
.tree-menu-2 ul .tree-menu-2:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 0px;
  height: 100%;
}

.tree-menu-2 ul li:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em;
  left: 0px;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0px 0 0 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 100%;
}

.tree-menu-2 ul .tree-menu-2:last-of-type:before {
  height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="tree-menu-1st-example">
    <ul>
        <li>
            Root
            <ul>
                <li>
                    Item1
                    <ul>
                        <li>item 1.1</li>
                        <li>item 1.1</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    Item2
                    <ul>
                        <li>item 1.1</li>
                        <li>item 1.1</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            <ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

      <div id="app">
         <div class="tree-menu-2">
            <li>
               <div class="label-wrapper">
                  <div class="has-children"><i class="fa fa-plus-square-o"></i>
                     root
                  </div>
               </div>
               <ul>
                  <div class="tree-menu-2">
                     <li>
                        <div class="label-wrapper">
                           <div class="has-children"><i class="fa fa-plus-square-o"></i>
                              item1
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <ul>
                           <div class="tree-menu-2">
                              <li>
                                 <div class="label-wrapper">
                                    <div class="">
                                       <!---->
                                       item1.1
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                                 <ul></ul>
                              </li>
                           </div>
                           <div class="tree-menu-2">
                              <li>
                                 <div class="label-wrapper">
                                    <div class="has-children"><i class="fa fa-plus-square-o"></i>
                                       item1.2
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                                 <ul>
                                    <div class="tree-menu-2">
                                       <li>
                                          <div class="label-wrapper">
                                             <div class="">
                                                <!---->
                                                item1.2.1
                                             </div>
                                          </div>
                                          <ul></ul>
                                       </li>
                                    </div>
                                 </ul>
                              </li>
                           </div>
                        </ul>
                     </li>
                  </div>
                  <div class="tree-menu-2">
                     <li>
                        <div class="label-wrapper">
                           <div class="">
                              <!---->
                              item2
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <ul></ul>
                     </li>
                  </div>
               </ul>
            </li>
         </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, the issue here is that my component is a recursive one. For your convenience I've prepared on how the HTML will look like after data is converted to li and ul tags and applied your css to it. Here is the codepen :- https://codepen.io/Dinesh443/pen/vYKPbVx    . The html looks kind of messed up because of this recursion. But that's how it is now. Could you please take a look it once.

Comment: I've updated css according to your html output. Root may need additional styling, but you should get the idea. Notice, that I changed before element's parent and gave that parent position relative. But mainly :last-of-type:before solves your dangling lines problem.

Comment: I hope you remember this question. I am having an issue with the line overflowing. I've copied the html and created this jsbin reproducer. [JS Bin Reproducer](https://jsbin.com/wacabuxihe/1/edit?html,css,output) . At certain point the lines are still overflowing.  You can see the image of my implementation here [Image Of My implementation](https://ibb.co/JQBFsxC) ,  I've just copied the li and ul tags generated by my vue code inside js bin along with the CSS . Any inputs here would be highly appreciated. Thanks!  Please let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

I have some different approach to solve the issue you.

```js
// modified data from array
var data = {
  id: 1,
  name: '',
  open: true,  // default open
  children: [{
      name: 'B',
      open: true,
      children: [{
        name: 'BC1',
        open: true,
        children: [{
          name: 'BC1-S',
          open: true,
          children: [{
              name: 'BC1-1'
            },
            {
              name: 'BC1-2'
            }
          ]
        }]
      },{
        name: 'BC2',
        open: true,
        children: [{
          name: 'BC2-S',
          open: true,
          children: [{
              name: 'BC2-1'
            },
            {
              name: 'BC2-2'
            }
          ]
        }]
      }]
    },
    {
      name: 'G',
      children: [{
        name: 'GC1',
        children: [{
          name: 'GC1-S1',
          children: [{
              name: 'GC1-1'
            },
            {
              name: 'GC1-2'
            }
          ]
        },{
          name: 'GC1-S2',
          children: [{
              name: 'GC1-3'
            },
            {
              name: 'GC1-4'
            }
          ]
        }]
      }]
    }
  ]
}

// define the item component
Vue.component('item', {
  template: '#item-template',
  props: {
    model: Object
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      open: this.model.open
    }
  },
  computed: {
    isFolder: function() {
      return this.model.children &&
        this.model.children.length
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggle: function() {
      if (this.isFolder) {
        this.open = !this.open
      }
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#main',
  data: {
    treeData: data
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Menlo, Consolas, monospace;
  color: #444;
}

.tree-view {}

.tree-view>ul {
  padding-left: 16px;
}

.tree-view li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 5px 0;
  position: relative;
}

.tree-view li:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.tree-view li::after,
.tree-view li::before {
  content: '';
  left: -30px;
  position: absolute;
  right: auto;
}

.tree-view li::before {
  border-left: 1px solid #405567;
  height: calc(100% + 10px);
  top: 0;
  width: 1px;
}

.tree-view li::after {
  border-top: 1px solid #405567;
  height: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  width: 35px;
}

.tree-view .item {
  border: 1px solid #405567;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px 6px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.tree-view .folder {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.tree-view>ul>li::after,
.tree-view>ul>li::before {
  border: 0;
}

.tree-view li:last-child::before {
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<script type="text/x-template" id="item-template">
  <li>
    <div class="item" :class="{folder: isFolder}" @click="toggle">
      <span v-if="isFolder">{{ open ? '-' : '+' }}</span> {{ model.name }}
    </div>
    <ul v-show="open" v-if="isFolder">
      <item v-for="(model, index) in model.children" :key="index" :model="model">
      </item>
    </ul>
  </li>
</script>

<div class="tree-view" id="main">
  <ul>
    <item :model="treeData">
    </item>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for an alternative soln. But I am so deep into my implementation with the existing code pen that I am not sure I can change it to your method. Is there any way the existing code pen can be changed to join the lines in a sane way ? Thanks!

Comment: Atleast I would like to know what is going on wrong with my implementation and why those extra lines are coming up. It would be very helpful if you can figure it out. Thank you very much once again.